# no other than and none other than

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, exam-questions

Is there any difference between “no other than” and “none other than.

This is one of questions came in my exam.

> ............ reason than poverty is hampering India’s progress.
>
> Options:
>
> 1) No other
>   2) None other
>   3) No another
>   4) No improvement

Correct Answer: No other

Why we rejected option **2**?

Comment: What do you already know about the words “no” and “none”?

Answer (score 1):

*No* is a determiner: it introduces a noun phrase, but it is not a noun phrase on its own. *No reason* is a noun phrase.

*None* is a pronoun: it can act as a noun phrase on its own. *None reason* is a noun phrase followed by a separate noun, and is not any kind of constituent of a sentence.

The addition of the modifying phrase *other than ...* doesn't change this.